# What ultimately happened to the Succubus?

Tags: video-games, aquanox, archimedean-dynasty

The *Succubus* was the ship that was piloted by *Emerald "Dead-Eye" Flint* while destroying the Survion and most of the Bionts. In the intro to Aquanox it is stolen, and we later learn that it was stolen by *Freeman* (a clear Half-Life reference). In Aquanox 2, *William Drake* takes on a job (optionally) to protect that *Freeman* fella, who seems unable to properly control the Succubus.

However, after that we never hear about that particular ship, nor that person, or did I miss something? Does Flint ever get his favourite ship back?

Answer (score 1):

Remember Aquanox and Aquanox 2 are set roughly at the same time. So in Aquanox 2 when you help Freeman get to the jumpship in an optional mission, Flint has put the word out. Hence, you come face-to-face with three subs, whose leader even advises you they want Freeman and to return his sub back to Flint.

If you listen to the chat, it explains why they are there to stop Freeman from getting on the jumpship.

Comment: Please re-read the second (and last) paragraph of the original question. It specifically asks for what happens *after* William Drake takes on the mission to protect Freeman.

Answer (score 0):

No one really knows, but I am assuming that the ship is most likely at the bottom of the sea, I mean there is an optional fight against Freeman in the instant action segment, so it could be that Flint ran into Freeman using his ship and basically decided to take him down, because why not?

Comment: This appears to be entirely speculation. If you have anything from the game to support this opinion, please [edit] it in.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the AquaNox 1 SinglePlayer , Instant fight, DUEL.

Freeman challenges Emerald Dead Eye Flint in a Duel with Flint using a much weaker ship while Freeman uses the Succubus.

They fight in the Magma ring close to the Argentine Basin. During the battle, Freeman constantly mocks Flint of how he can't do any damage only to realize that Flint is beating him.

At the very end, Flint destroys the Succubus along with Freeman.

Youtube Video

Answer (score -1):

The oceans are deep, wide and dark (okay, not so much in the Aquanox games), but it's probably not that easy to find a ship and get it back in one piece (also considering Flint got a better ship later on). Even if he wanted to, there are probably hundreds of thousands ships roaming the oceans.

It's been an interesting plot twist to explain starting out in a weak ship again, but I never really liked this explanation. It just sounds too weird. Why/how did he take the ship AI with him (considering he didn't want to give up the ship)? Aren't there any security measurements keeping someone from just hopping into someone else's ship? It's been the most modern fighter sub in whole Aqua and someone unable to pilot it properly has been able to hop in and hijack it? It's no simple jeep, it's a high tech ship with an AI and stuff.

In the end, he isn't happy about losing the ship (more likely due to having to start from scratch once again; not due to losing the specific ship), but due to the fact he's able to gain access to more advanced ships later on, I wouldn't expect him to specifically hunt Freeman down. If he runs into him, why not, but specifically looking for him? I don't think so. This most likely doesn't fit his personality as well. He's a mercenary, but the whole plot around Hong Long in the first game suggests that he's more than likely to grant mercy and let someone get away if there's no money or shooting at him involved.

Comment: Interesting comments, really. But how does that answer the question?

Comment: "Does Flint ever get his favourite ship back?" If he doesn't look for it, he doesn't get it back. What I tried to say: It's never been a central part of the story. It's just a short explanation for losing the original Succubus as well as a short backref in the third game. Also, he got over it pretty fast. I don't think there've been any official (canon) stories outside the game that could have explained this after the events of the third game?

Comment: I get your point. However, I've been under the impression that he had some attachment to that ship, other than just the specs (maybe that was projection from my part). Furthermore, were the ships he got in Aquanox really better? The Succubus had two freely programmable turrets.

Comment: From my understanding he's just been annoyed about losing his ship once again requiring him to start from scratch yet again. And once more it's just a cheap trawler not really made for fighting. As a mercenary you'd probably try to get a as-good-as-possible fighter boat. The new (later) ships are more advanced, e.g. DiPol drives being available to everyone due to EnTrOx being shattered. I'd consider the turret question being a gameplay issue.

Comment: I'm not ready to accept this, but I cannot remove the down vote either, unless you edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Remember the jumpship that crashed in Aquanox 1? Succubus was on board.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! This looks the like beginning to an answer. It would help you provide references to support the the claim. Since this is video maybe reference the level name or something.

Comment: I don't remember a jumpship crashing, nor any reference to the Succubus in this context.